# EF 4.2, Repository & UoW - how to include relationships?

Tags: entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, code-first

Been working with EF 4.2 but not with the repository or unit of work patterns. I'm trying to move to them but running into an issue. I've followed models where you create a repostirotybase abstract class, but having trouble crafting queries where i want to use the .Include() method for eager loading. Is this something you bake into the repository (so each repository would need to implement it) or further up at the layer that's consuming the data.

What's confusing is that if I have to put it in the repository (which appears to be the case), it's that limiting as then I have to provide a one size fits all to my consumers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create specific repository and add specific methods to load entity with relations. For example:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
    public Product GetProductWithFeatures(int key)
    {
        return context.Products
                      .Include(p => p.Features)
                      .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == key);
    }
}
```

Another approach is exposing `IQueryable` on your repository so you can call `Include` directly but such repository partially fails in decoupling your upper layer from EF.